# How to migrate from V2 to V3 Surveymonkey API

Tags: surveymonkey

I just received an error message that v2 is no longer supported.
I would have appreciated an email letting me know in good time that this was going to happen - I don't regularly login to Surveymonkey or Stackoverflow unless something has gone wrong.

Anyway, what is the quickest migration path?

Comment: I see Bill Manville is trying this too.  Bill, have you solved it ? http://stackoverflow.com/users/6787313/bill-manville

1. Does the authorization value start with "Bearer" as in the online doc or "bearer" as in some examples posted here?

2. Is the API_KEY needed? No according to the online doc but I have seen it in the examples here.

3. Does the surveys endpoint end with "v3/surveys" or "v3/surveys/" ?
I'm using MSXML2.XMLHTTP in VBA

I've emailed api-support so am waiting for help from them in their time zone.

Comment: I can now get a first page of 50 surveys, fine. Answers are 1. bearer ; 2 No ; 3 no trailing slash.  
Also: I don't need to URLEncode the request "?include=date_created" 
Lots to do.

Comment: Guys, your date fields now look like "2016-12-16T17:23:00" where they used to not have the T.  This is a load of work. Is there a comprehensive list of differences posted somewhere to aid migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migration help doc is [here](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Transitioning-to-SurveyMonkey-s-v3-API).

It can be "bearer" or "Bearer".

Depending on when you created your app you may have an API key listed in the credentials section for your app. If you have an API key, then you can use it the same way you did in V2. If you don't have one, then follow the [new authentication docs](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#new-authentication) and you don't need to pass one in the URL every time. If you still have an API key, but would rather not have to include one for every call, then refresh your credentials and you'll no longer need one.

It doesn't matter if you put a trailing slash or not.

When in doubt, look at the examples in the [V3 docs](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3) for formatting of content.

Comment: Thanks, Adam, that link is fairly brief. I would have liked SM to provide more info on the changes to data fields. I'll compile that myself.

Comment: And the docs are wrong - for example they show the query filters as json body when in fact they are tacked on to the end of the URL as query strings.

Comment: There were two spots (survey templates, survey responses bulk) in the docs where the requests get function incorrectly had the GET variables passed to the json argument. Did you notice any others?

Comment: No, I saw one and that discouraged me from trusting the code examples. However, I'm getting into it now so I think I've figured it out. Just have to restructure the data collection.